# Julia Function type annotation

Tags: types, julia

I`m new to Julia, so this might be a stupid question.

I have a type, with a function as an attribute, like:

```
struct exampleStruct
    someAtrribute::someType
    theFunction::Function
end
```

Is there a proper way to further specify the type of `theFunction` with regards to argument types and return types? In my case I know for sure that the instances of `theFunction` should only take arguments of type `Float64` and have return values of type `Float64`, e.g. I could write something like `theFunction::Function{Float64,...}{Float64}`.

I guess you could maybe make a subtype of `Function`, but I feel like that would require digging a fair bit deeper.

Comment: no, Julia does not have typed functions. Also, this struct is bad practice because `::Function` is an abstract type, just like `::Real` or `::Number`.

a better choice is `struct exampleStruct{T}` and `theFunction::T`

Comment: Thank you for the reply :) 

However I still don't quite understand how that would behave significantly differently. If you don't mind, please explain it to me, as I will still have to define `theFunction` as a function, which would still be of type `Function`,  since, as you explained, functions aren't typed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Julia every function has its own unique type. For example if you take function `sin`:

```
julia> typeof(sin)
typeof(sin) (singleton type of function sin, subtype of Function)
```

you can see that it has type that is displayed as `typeof(sin)`.
Additionally you get an information that this type is a subtype of abstract type `Function`. You can check this with:

```
julia> supertype(typeof(sin))
Function
```

Conversly, you can find all subtypes of `Funcion` type in your current Julia session by writing:

```
julia> subtypes(Function)
11259-element Vector{Any}:
 ArgTools.var"#1#11"
 ArgTools.var"#10#20"
 ArgTools.var"#2#12"
 ArgTools.var"#21#31"
 ⋮
 typeof(⊉) (singleton type of function ⊉, subtype of Function)
 typeof(⊊) (singleton type of function ⊊, subtype of Function)
 typeof(⊋) (singleton type of function ⊋, subtype of Function)
```

(this is the output on a fresh Julia 1.7.2 session)

Now it is crucial to understand that function type is associated with its name and the module in which the function was defined. For example let me `import` the `Statistics` module:

```
julia> import Statistics

julia> typeof(Statistics.mean)
typeof(Statistics.mean) (singleton type of function mean, subtype of Function)
```

Actually you can extract out type name and module where the function type was defined:

```
julia> Base.nameof(sin)
:sin

julia> Base.parentmodule(sin)
Base

julia> Base.nameof(Statistics.mean)
:mean

julia> Base.parentmodule(Statistics.mean)
Statistics
```

(this distinction is important as you can have in Julia many functions having the same name, but be defined in different modules)

So you can think of function type as being defined by function name and module. As you can see there is no argument types or return value type in definition of function type. Why is it so? The reason is that one function in Julia can have many methods. Function type itself does not provide any functionality - it is just a name and module in which the function name is defined. Only after you add methods to a function you have something that can be executed. Since you can have many methods of a given function each of this methods can have different types of arguments and different return value.

Let us check for `Statistics.mean` what methods it has defined:

```
julia> methods(Statistics.mean)
# 5 methods for generic function "mean":
[1] mean(r::AbstractRange{<:Real}) in Statistics
[2] mean(A::AbstractArray; dims) in Statistics
[3] mean(itr) in Statistics
[4] mean(f, A::AbstractArray; dims) in Statistics
[5] mean(f, itr) in Statistics
```

And you can add methods to a function later. Here is an example:

```
julia> function f end
f (generic function with 0 methods)

julia> methods(f)
# 0 methods for generic function "f":

julia> Base.nameof(f)
:f

julia> Base.parentmodule(f)
Main

julia> f(x::Integer) = 10x
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> methods(f)
# 1 method for generic function "f":
[1] f(x::Integer) in Main at REPL[26]:1

julia> f(x::String) = x^10
f (generic function with 2 methods)

julia> methods(f)
# 2 methods for generic function "f":
[1] f(x::Integer) in Main at REPL[26]:1
[2] f(x::String) in Main at REPL[28]:1
```

(in the example I show you that you can even define a function, with a new type that initially has no methods defined)

In summary:

- no function in Julia has `Function` type;
- every function in Julia has its own unique type that is subtype of `Function` abstract type;
- every function type is only identified by function name and module in which the function was defined.
- a single function type can have many methods that take different arguments and have different return value.

For these reasons in Julia it is impossible to specify the type of function with regards to argument types and return types (you can only specify it up to name and module where the function type was defined).

Now regarding the comment of @jling.

Your definition:

```
struct exampleStruct
    someAtrribute::someType
    theFunction::Function
end
```

is correct and will accept any function as `theFunction` argument. However, what is suggested that you create a parametric type instead:

```
struct exampleStruct{T<:Function}
    someAtrribute::someType
    theFunction::T
end
```

This recommendation is related to later performance of using the `exampleStruct`. If field type of `theFunction` is `Function` this is an abstract type and using abstract types as parameters in containers will degrade performance of your code as is explained in [this section](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/performance-tips/#man-performance-abstract-container) of the Julia Manual. However, if your code is not performance critical then you should be fine with your original definition.

As a final note, bear in mind that in Julia, there are callables that are not a subtype of `Function` type. Two most important cases are type constructors, e.g. you can call `Int` constructor, but `Int` is not a subtype of `Function`, and the second are functors, as explained in [this section](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/methods/#Function-like-objects) of the Julia Manual.

This means that in your definition of `exampleStruct`, if you restrict the second field type to `Function` you will disallow passing some callables as its arguments. Maybe this is not a problem in your case, but it is a common issue that is encountered when users try to create data structures that store functions as their fields.

Comment: Thank you Bogumił for your answer, it was very insightful.

Answer (score 3):

I'm fairly new to Julia, too. And I'm still learning to think in terms of multiple dispatch vs O-O ways. Types aren't objects exactly. You can make a struct callable like a function, but it doesn't support multiple function specifications in a struct like objects in O-O approaches.  Instead, the paradigm is to write functions that take the type as an argument.  In your case, something like:

function theFunction{x::exampleStruct, y, etc}

Comment: Thank you for the reply, however I am not trying to make an object with a method,
I am intentionally defining a type with a function as an attribute, because I need to define a data structure, that allows someone to specify some very broad parameters, on which to run some calculations. 

However I appreciate your reply  :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes there will certainly be a way to do that if you dig deep, but the question is: will you be using Julia that way? Then it'd be best if you stick to Python (or whatever language you're coming from), because you won't be utilising the full power Julia can offer you.

I have a question for your source code: is `exampleStruct` the only type on "earth" that works with a function called `theFunction`? If the answer is no, the point is why bother tying `thefunction` to `exampleStruct`. Follow the language's style if you want to enjoy it and use **MULTIPLE DISPATCH.**

Define `theFunction` outside and implement it for `exampleStruct`. Then when you need/have another type that uses `theFunction`, then go back and simply extend `theFunction` via multiple dispatch; this way you're in sync with Julia and would save yourself "unnecessary" complexity the language wasn't designed for.

A case in point is the `iterate` function in the Base module of Julia.

```
julia> Base.iterate
iterate (generic function with 230 methods)
```

Yes, you saw that right: **230** methods for just one function. So you see your question was not a foolish one, it only seeks to reveal the beauty of Julia.

The `iterate` function is dispatched for **230** different types. This is so easy to manage and scale; if you have a bug, just go to the type implemented by `iterate` that's causing the bug and then fix it. This way, you can easily add new types and then extend the `iterate` function. Could you have done this so easily if you were doing it in a classical **OOP-style** - yes, only if you're a veteran and would spend a month managing inheritance, dependencies and all those stuffs, just to fix a bug that's likely being caused by just one type.

So your question is a wise one; your `exampleStruct` would work perfectly on `theFunction` when its defined inside the type; but then when you want to scale, `multiple dispatch` would be your best bet.

Comment: I want to use a data structure that can describe the dependencies of various variables on other variables, with all underlying variables being pseudorandomly generated for the purposes of simulation. I want to use the example type to describe the dependency of a variable on 1 or more different variables, using an arbitrary user defined deterministic function. Ultimately I want to use the overarching data structure to build a graph and run some optimizations, that may be possible when I try to fit some variables against more than one data set at a time. One function may be used at many nodes.

Comment: Also I want to use the graph to check for cyclical dependencies,and generate an order of execution, for the values of each node, such that when I try to update the value of a node, I don't have to check if its dependencies are up to date.

Comment: If I'd be honest I didn't get the **MAIN GOAL** of what you're trying to do. You seem to want to do a lot, but breaking it down to one thing, what can it be generalised to?

Comment: A "user interface" to specify assumptions about a physical systems, in which different physical variables can have complex, user defined dependencies on different variables, for example, 2 Layers, which in total contain a set amount of a material, but the split can be varied. The user defined system can, by its nature, be conceived of as a directed acyclical graph, which is useful for optimization and stuff. I use the functions to express the relations between variables.

Comment: Well let me assume I know of what you're talking about as your intentions here seems to be very `domain-specific` and I'm dead sure my answers or opinions would be wrong, but anyway I'd give it. Just create the different physical systems and variables, and do it so well you can manage the complexities. Then sit down and think of the `functions` to apply to the different physical systems and variables, if they're general or not. If they're general, go for `multiple dispatch`, otherwise, do it separately.